# Запуск программы с запуском Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, автозапуск

Есть программа. Интересно, как сделать так, чтобы она запускалась вместе с Windows? Поместить ярлык в автозапуск не подходит. Может есть какая функция в `winAPI`, программа на С++

Comment: [На англоязычном SO эта тема уже разобрана](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722860/how-to-run-an-application-on-windows-start-up-in-win32-api-using-visual-c/1723083).

Answer (score 1):

Через реестр разве что.

1. Win+R
2. Ввести "regedit", enter
3. В строке ввести адрес "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
4. [Правая кнопка мыши]
5. Создать
6. Строковый параметр
7. В "Значение параметра" указать путь к файлу